# Can I view data for sqllocaldb using SQL Server Management Studio or other way to view/update/delete database data

Tags: c#, windows-services, service-accounts, sql-server-2014-localdb

I have a C# Windows application running with a virtual service account and a database is created in the user's profile folder.

[image]

The database connection string is,

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PersonContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=PersonDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[image]

Now since database is tight with virtual service user and I want to view the database data.

I am trying to use SQL Server Management Studio and trying to user default Windows auth, but off course this won't show the database,

[image]

My question is:

- Is this possible to view data using SSMS?
- If not what are the options I can view/edit/delete data?

Thanks!

Comment: using visual studio,open db in solution of your project.

Comment: In Server I don't have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: Right click on  Databases-> attach -> select .mdf file, this will add new DB on your sql server.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, this is one of the solution, but here I need to stop window service, attached database, make change, de-attached database and then re-start service.

Comment: I saw something `sqlcmd`, how to connect database using it and run update command, do you have idea?